# I have some problems when I test hadoop multi node cluster

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

**Hi
I'm using hadoop 0.23.9 with 2 node
when I tried the singel node it works fine but
when i try to test word count job I get the following result and I don't knew where the error**

I use ubuntu 12.04 LTS in both PCs

```
        mapred-site.xml


        <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
        </property>

        </configuration>

         yarn-site.xml


<configuration>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce.shuffle</value>
  </property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>master:8031</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>master:8032</value>
</property>


 <property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
  </property>

<property>
 <name>mapreduce.job.tracker</name>
  <value>master</value>
 </property>
<configuration>

<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce.shuffle</value>
  </property>




<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>master:8030</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>master:8032</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.address</name>
<value>0.0.0.0:8042</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

and here the hosts file of ubuntu

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.1.1       fatima1-HP-ProBook-4530s

192.168.1.10    master
192.168.1.11    slave

#the following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters









        14/04/25 15:41:39 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 7
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
        14/04/25 15:41:39 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:7
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated.    Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.combine.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.combine.class
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN conf.Configuration: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
        14/04/25 15:41:39 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
        14/04/25 15:41:39 INFO mapred.ResourceMgrDelegate: Submitted application application_1398429615167_0001 to ResourceManager at master/192.168.1.10:8032
        14/04/25 15:41:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: `http://master:8088/proxy/application_1398429615167_0001/`
        14/04/25 15:41:39 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1398429615167_0001
        14/04/25 15:41:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1398429615167_0001 running in uber mode : false
        14/04/25 15:41:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
        14/04/25 15:41:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1398429615167_0001_m_000006_0, Status : FAILED
    Container launch failed for container_1398429615167_0001_01_000008 : java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.startContainer(ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:396)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
    Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: ""fatima-HP-ProBook-4520s":45527; java.net.UnknownHostException; For more details see:  `http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnknownHost`
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine.java:144)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.startContainer(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.startContainer(ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.java:104)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: ""fatima-HP-ProBook-4520s":45527; java.net.UnknownHostException; For more details see:  `http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnknownHost`
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.<init>(Client.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1074)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine.java:141)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException
    ... 11 more

14/04/25 15:41:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1398429615167_0001_m_000006_1, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1398429615167_0001_01_000009 : java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.startContainer(ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:396)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: ""fatima-HP-ProBook-4520s":45527; java.net.UnknownHostException; For more details see:  `http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnknownHost`
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine.java:144)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.startContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.startContainer(ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.java:104)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: ""fatima-HP-ProBook-4520s":45527; java.net.UnknownHostException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnknownHost
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.<init>(Client.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1074)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine.java:141)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException
    ... 11 more

14/04/25 15:41:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1398429615167_0001_m_000006_2, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1398429615167_0001_01_000010 : java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.startContainer(ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:396)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: ""fatima-HP-ProBook-4520s":45527; java.net.UnknownHostException; For more details see:  `http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnknownHost`
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine.java:144)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.startContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.startContainer(ContainerManagerPBClientImpl.java:104)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: ""fatima-HP-ProBook-4520s":45527; java.net.UnknownHostException; For more details see:  `http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnknownHost`
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.<init>(Client.java:238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1194)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1074)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtoOverHadoopRpcEngine.java:141)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException
    ... 11 more

14/04/25 15:41:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 14% reduce 0%
14/04/25 15:41:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1398429615167_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1398429615167_0001_m_000006
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

14/04/25 15:41:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 5
    Job Counters 
        Launched map tasks=6
        Other local map tasks=3
        Data-local map tasks=7
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
```

Comment: Your hostname is not set correctly. Update/edit your post and add details around your OS and node configuration. The answer is in your above log, but much depends on what OS you're running and your node configuration.

Comment: post the /etc/hosts file and also paste the output of xxx$ hostname on the localhost. It sees your destination fatima-HP-ProBook-4520s but can't resolve your localhost

Comment: I post the /etc/hosts file above but i don't understand your another  question

Comment: in terminal on localhost type the command xxx$ hostname and paste the output. Also post the output of xxx$ jps

Comment: the output of hostname :fatima1-HP-ProBook-4530s and for jps :
4167 Jps
2793 NameNode
3609 NodeManager
3394 ResourceManager
3014 DataNode
3274 SecondaryNameNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying every possible solution to the problem, the solution was:
making the host name of the PC that work as master "master" and the slave "slave". 
After that entering the ip addresses of the PCs in the file "/etc/hosts".

Thanks a lot to Mr. apesa for his answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your hostname is not set correctly in /etc/hosts. You should remove the following line altogether.

```
127.0.1.1       fatima1-HP-ProBook-4530s
```

Then add your actual IP address right after the localhost entry. Your /etc/hosts file should look like this. 
NOTE: I am assuming this is the master, I may be wrong in which case replace it wiuth the actual IP address. Also check your destination machines /etc/hosts file as well.

```
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    192.168.1.10    fatima1-HP-ProBook-4530s

192.168.1.10    master
192.168.1.11    slave

the following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Once this has been completed you will need to reboot your machine and restart hadoop

EDIT:
Your core-site.xml has to have the correct master / slave entries as follows. You may have additional properties set within core-site.xml and that is fine. But in Distributed Mode you will need to specify a fs.default.name as a master or a slave.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried the configurations above But I get the same result

Comment: What I gave you above is correct for your /etc/hosts. Did you generate ssh master / slave keys? See above for core-site.xml recommendations

Comment: HI sorry for late
I tried every thing above and I had same result.

Comment: if I don't have domain name can make a problem??

Comment: You can try adding a full hostname by adding .localdomain to your hostname in your conf files (Core, yarn and mapred)-sites.xml.